# Knockoutjs: show content only if something its written in a textbox and hide it if the data is deleted

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an input text box. When a user starts typing something I want a div with some content to be shown. I was able to do something similar but only when the input loses focus with a subscription to its value. But I want the div to be visible at the moment the user has typed something, and to go hidden if the user deletes the data from the input, all this without losing focus of the input:

html:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: currentValue" />

<div data-bind="visible: hasData">
 Has Data  
</div>
```

javascript:

```
    var MyViewModel = function() {
      this.currentValue = ko.observable();
      this.hasData = ko.observable(false);

        this.currentValue.subscribe(function(newValue){
            if (newValue !== ""){
                this.hasData(true);
            }
            else{
                this.hasData(false);
            }
        }, this);
    }

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2Qnv7/115/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `hasData` as `computed observable`

```
var MyViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.currentValue = ko.observable();
    self.hasData = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.currentValue() !== "")
            return true;

        return false;
    });    
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

And then in the view use `valueUpdate`

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: currentValue, valueUpdate: 'afterKeyDown'" />

<div data-bind="visible: hasData">
   Has Data  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should to use `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html). Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/9yL68/